# How to start executing javascript code on page load?

Tags: javascript

I have a counter javascript code.It works fine but I want the counter to start executing onscroll but don't know how to do it. Any help with that?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
        var dataval = parseInt($('.progress').attr("data-amount"));
        if (dataval < 100) {
            $('.progress .amount').css("width", 0 + dataval + "%");
        }

        function modifyProgressVal(type) {
            dataval = parseInt($('.progress').attr("data-amount"));
            if (type == 1)
                dataval = Math.min(100, dataval + 10)
            else if (type == -1)
                dataval = Math.max(0, dataval - 10);
            $('.progress .amount').css("width", 100 - dataval + "%");
            $('.progress').attr("data-amount", dataval);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Use on scroll() event listener

Comment: Do you want to start executing on **page scroll** (question body) or **on page load** (title)?

Comment: I'd like to execute when I scroll down the page to the corresponing <div> that execute the script <div class="progress" data-amount="90 %">
  <div class="amount"></div>
</div>

Comment: What is `type` and how do you determine its value? Does it depend on the scrolling action, or on a user action? Is there a certain delay between calls of `modifyProgressVal`? If so, by what should that delay be determined? Currently you do not call this function at all (at least not in the question), so it is impossible to tell what you are really asking...

Answer (score 0):

You can add a scroll event listener on the document like so:

```
document.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
 // execute code on scroll
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The title and question are kinda confusing, but I think you might want your function to be called on load and on scroll; elaborating on Alex's answer, this should work:

```
document.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
    // execute code on scroll
});

document.dispatchEvent(new Event("scroll"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Add .scroll function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(document).scroll(function() {
    var dataval = parseInt($('.progress').attr("data-amount"));
    if (dataval < 100) {
        $('.progress .amount').css("width", 0 + dataval + "%");
    }

    function modifyProgressVal(type) {
    dataval = parseInt($('.progress').attr("data-amount"));
    if (type == 1) dataval = Math.min(100,dataval + 10)
    else if (type == -1) dataval = Math.max(0,dataval - 10);
    $('.progress .amount').css("width", 100 - dataval + "%");
    $('.progress').attr("data-amount", dataval);
}
}
```